# Can't delete a row with SQLAlchemy / Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't seem to get this method to delete a row. It runs without error, but the row remains in the db (mysql). I have add and updates working using a similar approach.

Basically, I'm creating a list of ids (ParentPage.id) and comparing those against a temp table (ParentPageTemp.id), with the intention of deleting rows in ParentPage which are not found in ParentPageTemp. Additional I have a relationship between ParentPage and Page where the row in Page should be deleted following the ParentPage delete. Admittedly my understanding of relationships in SQLAlchemy is novice at best.

models.py

```
class ParentPage(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent_page'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        this_id = str(self.id)
        return this_id

class Page(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent_page.id'), primary_key=True)  
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent_page.id'))
    type = Column(String(255))    
    default_code = Column(String(255))    
    name = Column(String(255))
    header = Column(String(255))
    title = Column(String(255))
    keywords = Column(String(255))    
    description = Column((Text)) 
    priority = Column(String(255))
    list_price = Column((Float))
    standard_price = Column((Float))
    image_filename = Column((Text))
    image_alt_text = Column(String(255))
    pdf_filename = Column((Text))
    lastupdate = Column(Date) 

    page = relationship('ParentPage', foreign_keys=[id], backref='page')
    parent = relationship('ParentPage', foreign_keys=[parent_id], backref='children') 

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

method in views.py

```
def delete_temp_not_in_test():
    parent_test_ids = db.session.query(ParentPage.id).all()
    print "parent in test - %s" % (parent_test_ids)
    for item in parent_test_ids:
        q = db.session.query(ParentPageTemp).get(item)
        if q is None:
            print "ID doesnt exist - %s" % (item)
            db.session.query(Page).filter(Page.id==item).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
            db.session.query(ParentPage).filter(ParentPage.id==item).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
            db.session.commit()
            print "%s deleted from Temp" % (item)
            # return False
        else:
            print "ID is %s" % (q.id)
            # return True
    return
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two relationships on Page but nothing in ParentPage.

Take a look: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

Add:

```
children = relationship("Page", backref='parent')
```

to ParentPage and remove the page relationship on Page you don't need it.

**Edit**
Sorry, maybe you want your relationship one to one, it's very similar.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I'm getting the error:
"
Was unable to import app Error: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ParentPage.page - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
" when I add the relationship "children" to Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is what you want:

1 - Add a `relationship` attribute and mention the `backref` column in `ParentPage` table, basically this `backref` will be like an added attribute to the `Page` model, by which and from `Page` model, you can get the `ParentPage` of the corresponding `Page` model:

```
class ParentPage(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent_page'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String(255))
    pages = relationship('pages', backref='parentpage')

    def __repr__(self):
        this_id = str(self.id)
        return this_id
```

2 - In `Page` model, specify only the `foreignKey` to `ParentPage`, as follows:

```
class Page(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)  #Leave this as a primary key
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent_page.id'))
    type = Column(String(255))   
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using your example and taking out ...

page = relationship('ParentPage', foreign_keys=[id], backref='page'), from Page(Model)
...runs in my app... however the delete function still doesn't effect the db.

Comment: @geoffn .. I see in your code that you have some `print` expression, that could help us narrow down the issue, can you post what output you get when you run this code?...

Comment: Thanks. My print calls displayed as expected... the correct ids, etc. I'm using Flask-Appbuilder, and ended up using it's native delete method for deleting out of ParentPage, and a regular SQLAlchemy delete for Page. I think your model/relationship advice helped out with the SQLAlchemy delete.